# How can I resolve this error in my PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, json, xampp

This is my PHP code to save json data from 'country.json' fle into a mysql table.

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db="jsondb";
$connect= new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die("ERROR:could not connect     to the database!!!");



$fo=fopen("country.json","r");
$fr=fread($fo,filesize("country.json"));
$array=json_decode($fr,true);

//To display all values from JSON file
//print_r($array);

$query="insert into country values('$array[name]','$array[code]')";

$connect->query($query);

echo "Data Imported Sucessfully from JSON!";
?>
```

the json file has more than 100 of entris like these :
    [{
      "name": "Afghanistan",
      "code": "AF"
    }, {
      "name": "Ã…land Islands",
      "code": "AX"
    }, {
      "name": "Albania",
      "code": "AL"
    }

But, after running this script in browser localhost, it gives errors :

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Suraj_Assignment_8\Suraj_Assignment_8.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: code in C:\xampp\htdocs\Suraj_Assignment_8\Suraj_Assignment_8.php on line 17
Data Imported Sucessfully from JSON!

How should I resolve it?

Comment: `var_dump($array);`. Oh look...

Comment: You cannot use such an "array construction" inside a SQL statement, however it actually was meant to work. You _can_ use a loop iterating over the array elements to create a list of fields and values though. Or you export to CSV and load that directly into your MySQL server.

Comment: You need to loop through your `$array`, give my answer a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your `$array`

change:

```
$query="insert into country values('$array[name]','$array[code]')";
```

to:

```
foreach ($array as $value){
    $query="insert into country values('".$value['name']."','".$value[code]."')";
    $connect->query($query);
}
```

Comment: Previously there were not single quotes around name and code in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
$query="insert into country values('".$array['name']."','".$array['code']."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this code as

```
  $query="insert into country values('".$array['name']."','".$array['code']."')";
```

Key should be in quotes. So here you could do as above or you can also escape sequence

```
  $query="insert into country values('$array[\"name\"]','$array[\"code\"]')";
```